# Weird charging pattern for 2019 MacBook Pro 16"

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I noticed this weird charging behavior (using [stats](https://github.com/exelban/stats)) when charging my Mac - charging power climbing and then dropping to ~60W over and over.

[image: screenshot]

Does this indicate a problem with the battery?

Comment: My initial thought is your batteries thermal management system doing its job. When this behavior occurs are you using your computer or is it sitting idle?

Comment: nothing wrong with that

Comment: Only start looking at stats when something has gone wrong. Otherwise, you're just giving yourself data to worry about.

Comment: @Salocor the laptop (and the batteries) were not hot. The amount of power draw by the operation of the laptop is visible in "System Total".

Comment: @VaidasKascėnas yeah that's what I mean. It looks like there's a spike in power when the charging speed drops off. If that's happening when the computer is idle there may be a problem with abckground applications but if it's happening during normal use that's normal. But I do agree with the other comments. Likely nothing wrong with the computer.